# Javascript modules with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, webpack

I'm trying to refactor client javascript in my nodejs/express application using CommonJS + Webpack modules.

With Webpack I build a 'bundle.js' made of two js files where I defined the two modules following CommongJS syntax. But on window.onload of the page I get a nice 'TypeError: moveTo.logHelloWorld is not a function" error.

Where am I wrong?

**Webpack configuration:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./public/js/common.js', './public/js/moveTo.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js'
  },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : []
}
```

**moveTo.js**

```
var moveTo = {};

console.log("moveTo.js loaded...");

moveTo.logHelloWorld = function(){
  console.console.log("Hello World logHelloWorld() from moveTo client Javascript!");
};

module.exports = moveTo;
```

**moveTo.handlebars**

```
<div>MoveTo</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    console.log("ON LOAD...");
    moveTo.logHelloWorld();
  }
</script>
```

and finally in the main template I included the bundle.js built with Webpack:

```
<script src="/bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is the error I got:

[image]

**UPDATE**: How to use multiple client js files
Suppose I would like to add another test.js file with its own module like so:

**test.js**

```
var test = {};

console.log("test.js loaded...");

test.logHelloWorld = function(){
  console.log("Hello World logHelloWorld() from TEST client Javascript!");
};

module.exports = test;
```

And then in **Webpack config**:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./public/js/common.js', './public/js/moveTo.js', './public/js/test.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
    library: ["moveTo", "test"] //This is not working.
  },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : []
}
```

How may I get this to work?

UPDATE: 
This is what i get using the suggested webpack configuration
[image]

## #LAST UPDATE#

Apparently there is no way to have a single **bundle.js** and get it to work with different javascript files. This is the only thing I reached so far with the precious help of @hazardous:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
// ['./public/js/common.js', './public/js/moveTo.js', './public/js/test.js'],
module.exports = {
  entry: './public/js/t3toolbox.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
    library: ["t3toolbox", "[name]"]
  },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : []
}
```

**t3toolbox.js**

```
var t3toolbox = {}; // Global App NameSpace
var test = require('./test.js');
var moveTo = require('./moveTo.js');

t3toolbox.moveTo = moveTo;
t3toolbox.test = test;

module.exports = t3toolbox;
```

**moveTo.js**

```
var moveTo = {};

console.log("moveTo.js loaded...");

moveTo.logHelloWorld = function(){
  console.log("Hello World logHelloWorld() from MOVETO client Javascript!");
};

module.exports = moveTo;
```

**test.js**

```
var test = {};

console.log("test.js loaded...");

test.logHelloWorld = function(){
  console.log("Hello World logHelloWorld() from TEST client Javascript!");
};

module.exports = test;
```

**moveTo.handlebars**

moveTo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    console.log("ON LOAD...");
    t3toolbox.main.moveTo.logHelloWorld();
    t3toolbox.main.test.logHelloWorld();
  }
</script>
```

As you can see you still have to use the *main* after t3toolbox. I never accomplished the configuration where you end up with

```
var mylibrary = {
  moveTO: {/*...*/},
  test: {/*...*/}
}
```

It always end up with:

```
var mylibrary = {
  main: {
    moveTo: {/*...*/},
    test: {/*...*/}
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the script tag added?

Comment: Do you mean the last one with bundle.js? This script tag is included in the main.handlebars layout of the application.

If you instead refer to the one where I call the moveTo.logHelloWorld() function, that tag is added to the end of the moveTo.handlebars template that refers to the page where I would like to call the function mentioned.

Comment: Try by adding this script tag inside header

Comment: From the webpack config snippet, it is not clear what is the libraryTarget configured to. If its not there, webpack uses the `var` option, but that needs library.name to be defined as well. Please share the complete webpack config, if possible.

Comment: @hazardous I added the complete webpack configuration file.

Comment: @brk which script tag do you mean? The one for bundle.js? I think this is not the problem because as you can see the "moveTo.js loaded..." string get exectuted correctly.

Comment: Also, what's inside common.js? Do you really need to bundle it in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `library` to `output` configuration, like so -

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./public/js/common.js', './public/js/moveTo.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
    library: 'moveTo'
  },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : []
}
```

If your library has several exported entities, use this -

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./public/js/common.js', './public/js/moveTo.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
    library: ["mylibrary", "[name]"]
  },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : []
}
```

This example is based on https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/multi-part-library/webpack.config.js#L10.

This example configuration will create an export of this form:

```
var mylibrary : {
    "common": {/* exports from common */},
    "moveTo": {/* exports from moveTo */}
}
```

So you can use them in your code using `mylibrary.common`, `mylibrary.moveTo` etc.

If you don't want to club all of your imports in "mylibrary", you can change the `library` to -

```
library:"[name]"
```

This will create separate `var moveTo = ...` and `var test = ...` exports.

Comment: It works!! Thank you!
But what if I would like to add another module to the list, to be called in another page? Should I use an array for the library configuration?

Comment: Updated the answer to support multi-export lib. Also, please accept the answer if it solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: In `library: ["mylibrary", "[name]"]`, `"[name]"` should be kept as it is, do not replace it with `test` :). It is a special placeholder which is replaced by the name of the entry. So once you fix this, the output library will be of this shape - `mylibrary:{"common":..., "moveTo":..., "test" : ...}`. Hope this is less confusing now :).

Comment: Updated my example with usage info.

Comment: I changed as you said leaving the _["mylibrary", "[name]"]_ string as it is, but the mylibrary has only a main key with only the function from the test.js file. More on the updated question.

Comment: Could you share a minimal repro code? It'd be faster that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144058/discussion-between-hazardous-and-roberto).